# Custom scale for image plots?

Tags: plot, ilnumerics

Now that we have Image plots capability in ILNumerics, I am replacing all my code to use ImageSc plots inplace of surface plots.

For surface plots, we can specify X and Y scale values in the form of grid. Is there any way to modify the index based scale values for image plots without overwriting TickCreationFunction?

Comment: Not by v4.6. But we'll consider that as an useful addition to one of the next releases. Please file it as a feature request: http://ilnumerics.net/mantis

Answer (score 1):

you could place the plot inside a group and use the group to translate the plot inside the plot cube:

```
private void ilPanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ilPanel1.Scene.Add(new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: false) {
        new ILGroup(translate: new Vector3(-5,10,100)) {
            new ILImageSCPlot(ILSpecialData.sincf(10,20))
        }
    });
}
```

This would work with any plot object - not only ImageSC.

Comment: This shifts the whole ImageSCPlot around. Nice solution if the grid is still regular and an offset to the axis is all what is needed. Plus 1.